# missing ";" in insert query c# access database

Tags: c#, insert, sql-order-by

```
string query = "insert into TraineeDetail values('" + trainee.TyNo + "','" +
trainee.PersonalNumber.ToString() + "','" + trainee.TraineeName.ToString() + "','" + 
trainee.Rank.ToString() + "','" + trainee.Division.ToString() + "','" + trainee.ENMATEL + "','" + 
trainee.ENMATMECH + "','" + trainee.ENMATGSC + "','" + trainee.MAXM.ToString() + "','" + 
trainee.SUBBR.ToString() + "') order by MAXM desc ";
```

i m getting error- missing semicolon (;) at the end of the sql statement

any solution

Comment: I have never seen an INSERT INTO together with an ORDER BY

Comment: `order by MAXM desc ";` => `order by MAXM desc; "`

Comment: Please [parameterize your variables](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) - It has security (SqlInjection) and performance (plan cache) benefits

Comment: @Steve StackOverflow is an amazing community - always something new...

Answer (score 4):

`INSERT` statements are used for just that. Inserting data.

You appear to be using it combined with an `ORDER BY`. What do you intend to order?

`ORDER BY` is generally used when you are `SELECT`'ing data. As in, "I want this data, but order it in this way before you show it to me".

Remove the `ORDER BY` and your query will work.

Please also investigate SQL injection and SqlParameters. As it is, your code is very insecure.

Comment: I'd add that if you use parametrized commands, you won't need any ";" at the end.

Comment: earlier i tried like this
 string query = "select TOP " + TraineesPerBlock + "  * from TraineeDetail  where SUBBR = '0' order by MAXM desc" ;

here in traineesPerBlock when value was passesd 69 i got 110 record, i should get 69 only.. MAXM is a double field, also there are records having same MAXM value.

why i am getting 110 records instead of 69??

Comment: That's an entirely different question to what you've asked. Please create a new one for that.